# @OneToOne is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, sql

No entiendo por qué me tira este error. Simplemente estoy tratando de mapear una relación "one to one" usando esta anotación. Cabe destacar que el error también me lo tira en la línea siguiente con la anotación @JoinColumn (dice exactamente lo mismo: "is disallowed for this location"). Busqué otros tutoriales y la verdad que no encontré respuesta. Intenté googlear el error y tampoco encontré nada. Curiosamente ni el profesor ni ninguno de los alumnos que sigue el curso les pasó lo mismo.

```
package entidades;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    String nombre;
    @Column(name ="apellido")
    String apellido;
    @Column(name="direccion")
    String direccion;
    
    private Detalles_Cliente detallescliente;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    
    public Cliente(String nombre, String apellido, String direccion) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

//getters y setters
    

}
```

Comment: ¿Pero que estás intentando mapear? ¿El contructor? La anotación `@OneToOne` no la has colocado en ningún atributo. Si lo que quieres anotar es `detallescliente` para enlazar las tablas, coloca las anotaciones `@OneToOne` y  `@JoinColumn` antes del atributo ¡No después!

Comment: gracias que tonto no me di cuenta